# Black lines in rendered video when stacking multiple videos in one screen using Blender

Tags: animation, video, render, blender, video-processing

I have stacked (combined) multiple videos (to play them simultaneously) into 3x1 columns by rows. These videos have the same background color. So I added a color (the same as their background using the pick color tool). However, I observed that some black lines appeared in the rendered (animation) output at the intersection between the stacked videos.

These lines only appear during rendering and in the video output. However, it disappeared from the composing screen. I have tried to set Compositing>Blend to Overlay. However, the issues are still unable to be resolved. Could you please instruct me on how to remove those black lines? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are all of your videos the same fps?  If not that may be causing the issue.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me. One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.